# Filtering batch output

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to filter the output of a batch file using regex or anything similar ?

In short this is my scenario : I need to clean up log files for further analysis, but due to the size of them I want to downsize them first. The original file is a space delimited file, and I know that for each line the 5th item is what I need.

So far so good, the following file kind of gives me what I need :

```
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion
@title = logger


for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.log) do call :getURI %%a

pause
goto :eof

:getURI

echo %5 >> cleaned.txt
goto :eof

:eof
```

This gives me the desired output as follows

```
some_url.html
test.html
some_other_url.html
test.html
test.html
yet_another_url.html
...
```

Now, it still takes an awful lot off time to generate this file, so I was wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this, and whether it would be possible to filter the output also. I still have for instance quite some [test.html] in the output (fictional example) and I prefer to strip them out upfront, so my outcome would become

```
some_url.html
some_other_url.html
yet_another_url.html
...
```

Any advices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - pure native batch**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>cleaned.txt (
  for /f "tokens=5" %%A in (
    'findstr /rvc:"^ *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *test.html" test.log'
  ) do echo %%A
)
```

The following strategies from above are what improves performance:

- Use FINDSTR to pre-filter out all test.html lines
- Eliminate CALL by using FOR /F to parse the 5th token directly
- Redirect only once using an outer parentheses block

***Update***

As discussed in [this follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23913449/1012053), this solution becomes horribly slow when dealing with very large files. Good performance can be restored by using a temporary file.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
findstr /rvc:"^ *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *test.html" test.log >test.log.mod
>cleaned.txt (for /f "tokens=5" %%A in (test.log.mod) do echo %%A)
del test.log.mod
```

**Option 2 - my REPL.BAT utility**

I have written a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that can directly give the desired result very efficiently. It performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. It is pure script that will run natively on any modern Windows machine from XP onward.

```
type test.log | repl "^ *(\S+ +){4}(?!test.html |test.html$)(\S*).*" $2 a >cleaned.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This should run faster than your original code, and also eliminate `test.html`:

```
echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion
@title = logger

(for /f "tokens=5" %%a in (test.log) do (
   if "%%a" neq "test.html" echo %%a
)) > cleaned.txt

pause
```

Comment: Don't you want to disable delayed expansion? Also, you are missing a closing paren.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    ( for /f "tokens=5" %%a in (test.log) do @echo(%%a
    ) | findstr /v /b /c:"test.html" /c:"another_test.html" > cleaned.txt

    endlocal
```

The for command will tokenize the lines of the input file, splitting on spaces (default behaviour). We are only interested in the 5th one (`tokens=5`) that will be echoed. The output of the `for` command execution is piped to `findstr` that will show all the lines that does not contain (`/v`) at the begin of the line (`/b`) any of the indicated strings (`/c:"..."`)

Comment: Thanks MC, unfortunatly this did not really do the trick, it seams to work only if both the exceptions are on teh same line, which doesn't really happen. I managed however to work further on your example, and following did work "findstr /v "test another_test". Maybe not the safest way to do this but it works in my case

Comment: @Wokoman, not sure where you have found a problem. For me, it is working as far as the text is at the start of the line (it should be if this is the 5th field).

Answer (score 0):

You could run -v option in grep which inverts all the matching lines, giving you all lines that 'dont' match the search.

```
grep -v "test.htm" > newfile.log
```

[Explanation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control)of -v is at Gnu website.

Commands can be pipped together as many times as you want:

```
 grep -v "firstunwanted" * | grep -v "secondunwanted" > newfile.log
```